# Computing argument values dynamically

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode

When I'm passing arguments to a `#+begin_src` block, is there a way to compute them dynamically?

Specifically, I want to set the `:height` attribute to something that depends on some variables in my `R` code, like in the following mockup:

```
#+begin_src R
x <- 5
#+end_src

#+begin_src R :results graphics :file foo.svg :height (3*getvar('x'))
...draw picture here
#+end_src
```

where that `getvar()` thing, and computations therewith, is maybe my wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Org-mode now interprets brackets in the header specs as elisp so you can do this with some elisp in between:

Named R src block

```
 #+name: default-height
 #+begin_src R
   x <- 300
 #+end_src

 #+results: default-height
 : 300
```

Make the result from R an emacs variable

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var incoming = default-height :results silent
  (setq dh incoming)
#+end_src
```

Use of elisp in source block header

```
#+begin_src R :results graphics :file test.png :height (* dh 3)
  plot(rnorm(100))
#+end_src

#+results:
[[file:test.png]]
```

Works for me :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for showing that.  For some reason though, even though my `org-babel-load-languages` is set to `((emacs-lisp . t) (sh . t) (plantuml . t) (R . t) (perl . t))`, I've never been able to get `emacs-lisp` blocks working.

Comment: What's the error with the emacs-lisp blocks?  org-babel-load-languages looks ok.  You might be able to ditch the in-between elisp code is you can work out how to reference the R result you want to use (default-height in my example above) directly as elisp code.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to use org-mode to do that, but this is already a feature in the `knitr` package (an alternative to Sweave), so if you do not mind the Sweave syntax, you can use:

```
<<>>=
x <- 5
<<foo, dev='svg', fig.height=3*x>>=
# draw plots here
@
```

More on org-mode in `knitr`: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/org/